# Ionic 3 form validation confirm password

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am building registration form in Ionic 3, I have two fields password1 and password2 and the requirement is password2 must be same as password1.

My component:

```
public registration : FormGroup;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

        this.registration = this.formBuilder.group({
            username: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'), Validators.required])],
            email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.email, Validators.required])],
            password1: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(5), Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'), Validators.required])],
            password2: ['', Validators.required],
        }, (registration: FormGroup) => {
            return PasswordValidator.areEqual(registration);
        });
    }

    validation_messages = {
        'username': [
        { type: 'pattern', message: 'Username must contain only combination of letterns and numbers.' },
        { type: 'required', message: 'Username is required.' }
        ],
        'email': [
        { type: 'required', message: 'Email is required.' },
        { type: 'email', message: 'Not a valid email!' }
        ],
        'password1': [
        { type: 'minlength', message: 'Password must be minimum 5 characters.' },
        { type: 'required', message: 'Password is required.' },
        { type: 'pattern', message: 'Password must contain combination of upper and lower case letterns and numbers.' }
        ],
        'password2': [
        { type: 'required', message: 'Password is required.' },
        { type: 'areEqual', message: 'Confirm password is not same.' },
        ],

    }
```

I have created a password validator in a separate file (not sure if it's the correct way):

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export class PasswordValidator {
static areEqual(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    let val;
    let valid = true;

    for (let key in formGroup.controls) {
        if (formGroup.controls.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            let control: FormControl = <FormControl>formGroup.controls[key];
            if (val === undefined) {
                val = control.value
            } else {
                if (val !== control.value) {
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (valid) {
        return null;
    }
    return {
        areEqual: true
    }
 }
}
```

And my template:

```
<!-- Registration Form -->
<form *ngSwitchCase="'registrationForm'" [formGroup]="registration" (ngSubmit)="register()" autocomplete="off">

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Username</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="username"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <!-- Username validation errors -->
    <div class="validation-errors">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.username" >
            <div class="error-message" *ngIf=" registration.get('username').hasError(validation.type) 
            && ( registration.get('username').dirty || registration.get('username').touched)">
                {{ validation.message }}
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>


    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="email" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <!-- Email validation errors -->
    <div class="validation-errors">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.email" >
            <div class="error-message" *ngIf=" registration.get('email').hasError(validation.type) 
            && ( registration.get('email').dirty || registration.get('email').touched)">
                {{ validation.message }}
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>


    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Password1</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" formControlName="password1"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <!-- Password1 validation errors -->
    <div class="validation-errors">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.password1" >
            <div class="error-message" *ngIf=" registration.get('password1').hasError(validation.type) 
            && ( registration.get('password1').dirty || registration.get('password1').touched)">
                {{ validation.message }}
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Password2</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" formControlName="password2"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <!-- Password2 validation errors -->
    <div class="validation-errors">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.password2" >
            <div class="error-message" *ngIf=" registration.get('password2').hasError(validation.type) 
            && ( registration.get('password2').dirty || registration.get('password2').touched)">
                {{ validation.message }}
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>

    <button ion-button full type="submit" [disabled]="!registration.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

All other validations work properly i.e. correct messages are printed. Password2 validation works only for empty password and do not work for checking if it is same with password1.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I am checking password and confirm password by this way.

Html file

```
<ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" clearinput [(ngModel)]="user.password" required formControlName="password">
            </ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item no-lines
                  *ngIf="ChangePassword.get('password').hasError('minlength') && ChangePassword.get('password').touched"
                  class="invalid">
            <p class="error_message">* Minimum password length is 6!</p>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item no-lines
                  *ngIf="(ChangePassword.get('password').hasError('required') ) && ChangePassword.get('password').touched">
            <div class="error"
                 *ngIf="ChangePassword.get('password').hasError('required') && ChangePassword.get('password').touched">
                <p class="error_message">* Password is required</p>
            </div>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Conform Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" clearinput [(ngModel)]="user.password_confirmation" required
                       formControlName="password_confirmation">
            </ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item no-lines
                  *ngIf="ChangePassword.get('password_confirmation').hasError('minlength') && ChangePassword.get('password_confirmation').touched"
                  class="invalid">
            <p class="error_message">* Minimum password length is 6!</p>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item no-lines
                  *ngIf="(ChangePassword.get('password_confirmation').hasError('equalTo') || ChangePassword.get('password_confirmation').hasError('required') ) && ChangePassword.get('password_confirmation').touched">

            <div class="error"
                 *ngIf="ChangePassword.get('password_confirmation').hasError('required') && ChangePassword.get('password_confirmation').touched">
                <p class="error_message">* Confirm password is required</p>
            </div>
            <div class="error"
                 *ngIf="ChangePassword.get('password_confirmation').hasError('equalTo') && ChangePassword.get('password_confirmation').touched">
                <p class="error_message">* Password Mismatch</p>
            </div>
        </ion-item>

        <button ion-button block class="auth-action-button login-button" type="submit"
                [disabled]="!ChangePassword.valid">
            Submit
        </button>
```

Ts file

```
this.ChangePassword = new FormGroup({
            // token: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
            email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
            password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(15)]),
            password_confirmation: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(15), this.equalto('password')])
        });


equalto(field_name): ValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
            let input = control.value;
            let isValid = control.root.value[field_name] == input;
            if (!isValid)
                return {'equalTo': {isValid}};
            else
                return null;
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this works well for me

```
this.profileForm  = this.fb.group({
          name: ['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(3),Validators.maxLength(25)]],
          password: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(5),Validators.required,Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$')])],
          confirmPass: ['',Validators.required],
          /*title_ar: ['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(3),Validators.maxLength(30)]],
          desc_en: ['',[Validators.required]],*/
      },{validator: this.checkIfMatchingPasswords('password', 'confirmPass')})



    checkIfMatchingPasswords(passwordKey: string, passwordConfirmationKey: string) {
        return (group: FormGroup) => {
            let passwordInput = group.controls[passwordKey],
                passwordConfirmationInput = group.controls[passwordConfirmationKey];
            if (passwordInput.value !== passwordConfirmationInput.value) {
                return passwordConfirmationInput.setErrors({notEquivalent: true})
            }
            else {
                return passwordConfirmationInput.setErrors(null);
            }
        }
```